# Create Setup package runtime in .NET

Tags: .net, setup-deployment

I want to create one application which created Setup file for Window Desktop application runtime with all resource file which application needed.

Is this possible? If yes then how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your .sln in VS/Add/New Project/Other Project Types/Setup and Deployment/Setup Project
Now
Application Folder/Add/Project Output/Your app + whichever parts of your app you want deployed.

Also, to have the resource files included - you can either embed them in your executable or make them copied to your output directory (file/Properties/"Build Action" & "Copy to Output Directory")

Comment: Hi xyzzer

Thanks for your update my problem is i have create one online flash screen saver generator now every user upload file runtime for screensaver image, then they are going to generate exe (setup file of screensaver) so for each user i need to change resource file dynamically and want to generate setup file for that automatic 

so how can i do this ?